# Nuxt js keep old input values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

i am trying to build an app where user inputs some data and then press a button to a next step. The problem is when i am on the next page i have another button which takes you back to the previous step, the page renders all and well but the inputs are empty, i want to display previously entered data. My first page looks like this

```
<template>
<div class="py-4">
  <h1 class="text-center text-4xl py-5">Welcome!</h1>
  <div class="max-w-4xl flex m-auto">
    <div class="shadow-lg bg-white rounded-lg py-10 px-20 flex flex-col justify-between leading-normal">
      <div class="mb-3 bg-red-100 border border-red-400 text-red-700 px-4 py-3 rounded relative alert" role="alert" v-if="errors.length">
        <strong class="font-bold">Please correct the following error(s):</strong>
        <p>
          <ul>
            <li v-for="error in errors">{{ error }}</li>
          </ul>
        </p>
        <span class="absolute top-0 bottom-0 right-0 px-4 py-3">
          <svg class="fill-current h-6 w-6 text-red-500" role="button" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" @click="dismiss">
            <title>Close</title>
            <path
              d="M14.348 14.849a1.2 1.2 0 0 1-1.697 0L10 11.819l-2.651 3.029a1.2 1.2 0 1 1-1.697-1.697l2.758-3.15-2.759-3.152a1.2 1.2 0 1 1 1.697-1.697L10 8.183l2.651-3.031a1.2 1.2 0 1 1 1.697 1.697l-2.758 3.152 2.758 3.15a1.2 1.2 0 0 1 0 1.698z" />
          </svg>
        </span>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-8">
        <div class="text-gray-900 font-bold text-xl mb-2">Terms of Use</div>
        <ul class="list-disc ml-10">
          <li>Glider requires some personally-identifiable information (name, email, etc.) in order to complete this
            assessment.</li>
          <li>To understand more about our privacy policy, data capture, data processing, etc., you can read our
            privacy policy and terms and service.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="flex items-center">
        <div class="mb-4 w-2/4">
          <label class="text-gray-700 leading-none" for="location">
            Current location<span class="text-red-600">*</span>
          </label>
          <select class="block appearance-none w-100 bg-white border border-gray-400 hover:border-gray-500 py-2 rounded shadow leading-tight mt-2" v-model="country" :value="country" name="location">
            <option v-for="country in countries" v-bind:key="country.code" v-bind:value="country.name">
              {{country.name}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-4 w-2/4">
          <label class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" for="username">
            City, State
          </label>
          <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight" id="username" type="text" placeholder="City, State" v-model="state">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="bg-blue-100 border border-blue-200 rounded text-blue-700 px-4 py-3" role="alert">
        <input type="checkbox" name="terms" v-model="terms" />
        <label for="terms" class="text-sm align-middle">I agree to the above terms..</label>
      </div>
      <a class="mt-4 m-auto duration-75 text-center w-1/4 bg-green-500 cursor-pointer hover:bg-green-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full" @click="submit">
        Next Step
      </a>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      errors: [],
      state: this.state,
      country: this.country,
      terms: this.terms,
      countries: [{
          name: 'Afghanistan',
          code: 'AF'
        },
        {
          name: 'Åland Islands',
          code: 'AX'
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submit: function(e) {
      this.errors = [];
      if (!this.state) {
        this.errors.push('State is required!');
        return;
      }
      if (!this.country) {
        this.errors.push('Country is required!');
      }
      if (!this.terms) {
        this.errors.push('You need to accept the terms!');
      }
      if (this.errors.length == 0) {
        this.$router.push("details")
      }

    },
    dismiss: function(e) {
      this.errors = [];
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style scoped>
ul>li {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
</style>
```

How can i display the data when user returns back to `/` route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved the results by using `localStorage`.

```
<script>
export default {
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      errors: [],
      state: localStorage.getItem('state'),
      country: localStorage.getItem('country'),
      terms: localStorage.getItem('terms'),
      countries: [{
          name: 'Afghanistan',
          code: 'AF'
        },
        {
          name: 'Åland Islands',
          code: 'AX'
        },
       ...
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submit: function(e) {
      this.errors = [];
      if (!this.state) {
        this.errors.push('State is required!');
      }
      if (!this.country) {
        this.errors.push('Country is required!');
      }
      if (!this.terms) {
        this.errors.push('You need to accept the terms!');
      }
      if (this.errors.length == 0) {
        console.log(this.country,this.state,this.terms);
        let terms_of_use = {'country': this.country, 'state': this.state, 'terms': this.terms};
        localStorage.setItem('country', this.country);
        localStorage.setItem('state', this.state);
        localStorage.setItem('terms', this.terms);
        this.$router.push("details")
      }

    },
    dismiss: function(e) {
      this.errors = [];
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: you can also have achieved that with a store manager (like `vuex`) or passing values via props from the main component to the other ones. You can find more here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html